# Add column VS Recreating table

Tags: sql-server

I was going through some SQL Scripts a coworker had wrote to upgrade a table to a newer version.  It was simply adding a new column to the table.  However, instead of a

```
ALTER TABLE [Table] ADD [Column] [DataType]
```

statement, he instead made a copy of the table with the new column, repopulated it with the existing data, deleted the old table, renamed the new one to the old table, and then re-added all the indexes and relationships.

My question is, is there any benefit to doing this rather than the simple Alter statement or is there any difference?

I can't imagine all that work for practically no difference other than the column's ordinal position being in the desired place.

Comment: Did he for some reason want the column to be in a specific location in the table, i.e., not just tagged on to the end?  Maybe the column was not nullable and he chose to delete the whole table instead of adding a nullable column, populating it, and then adding the constrant?

Comment: Another reason would be to have the table create script be self contained.  If a reload needs to occur due to crash and tables have to be re-created, then it's easier to run the one create statement instead of it and then all the alters.  May be related to "Version control" in other words.  If 20 alters over a period of years occur and then you have to recreate the table, someone has to remember the 20 alters.  one table one script 20 versions is "easier" to manage I think.

Comment: @Tom The column can be null and there's not relationships regarding the column so i don't think that is the case.

Comment: @xQbert I don't think this is the case either because this is only run for database updates.  If a new database was created using this schema, then the column would have already been included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the SSMS GUI, it will sometimes take this approach.  One possible reasons for doing it this way is "Inserting" a column rather than "appending" a column.  (if you want the column to appear before some already existing columns.)  In that case, adding a column won't work.

Essentially, any time a simple addition of a new column to the end of the table isn't what you're looking for.  But my guess is that he used the GUI to add the column and chose the "generate SQL script" option.

Comment: Ahhh didn't know you could do that for alters on table in SSMS.  This might've been what he did.  But for performance wise, there's nothing different is there?

Comment: I checked and this was indeed what he did. Thank you.

Comment: Well, performance for ADD COLUMN is definitely faster than creating a new table, etc.  Is that what you were asking?

Comment: No i meant queries on the table and etc.  Not the actual alteration/creation itself.

Comment: That's correct.  The order of the columns in the table will have no impact on query performance.

Answer (score 1):

Just a couple of differences on how that would be different. Hope this helps!

**Adding new column to existing table:**

*Pros:*

- No need to recreate indices and constraints on the existing table.
- 2. Data on existing column remains intact.

*Cons:*

- Huge table that has millions of records will need to be updated for
  the new column.

**Recreating a New Table:**

*Pros:*

- No need to worry for any kind of limits (number of columns, total
  size of table) in the RDBMS

*Cons:*

- Recreate indices and constraints
- Reload data for all columns